Cannot connect with kafka-ui to kafka
I start kafka locally with
$ docker run -p 9092:9092 apache/kafka:3.7.1
$ docker exec -it gifted_wright /bin/bash
e8bebba64b30:/$ cd /opt/kafka/bin
e8bebba64b30:/opt/kafka/bin$ sh kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic my-first-topic --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
Created topic my-first-topic.
e8bebba64b30:/opt/kafka/bin$ sh kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
my-first-topic

I then can connect e.g. with the kafka plugin of IntelliJ Idea.
Then I start the kafka ui with
$ docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -e DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED=true ghcr.io/kafbat/kafka-ui

When creating a cluster with only configureing bootstrap servers to be localhost:9092
9:44:45,536 INFO  [kafka-admin-client-thread | kafbat-ui-admin-1721382278-2] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=kafbat-ui-admin-1721382278-2] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-07-19 09:44:45,537 WARN  [kafka-admin-client-thread | kafbat-ui-admin-1721382278-2] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=kafbat-ui-admin-1721382278-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Then a port fowarding is created which gives "Name does not resolve"
$ docker exec -it --user=root nice_wright /bin/sh
/ # apk add socat
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.4_p20231125-r0)
(2/4) Installing libncursesw (6.4_p20231125-r0)
(3/4) Installing readline (8.2.1-r2)
(4/4) Installing socat (1.8.0.0-r0)
Executing busybox-1.36.1-r15.trigger
OK: 191 MiB in 26 packages
/ # socat tcp-listen:9092,fork tcp:host.docker.internal:9092

When clicking on validate in the ui I get
2024/07/19 09:42:59 socat[94] E getaddrinfo("host.docker.internal", "9092", {0x20,0,1,6}, {}): Name does not resolve

How to connect? Am I missing something central?

Localhost refers to the UI container itself. Then accessing via the Docker host address isn't going to work without extra configuration and not necessary. You'll need to create a shared docker network and link the containers

Could solve the issue with the hints in comment from OneCricketeer
I created a network like explained on docker. Both started containers could ping each other both by hostname and IP-address. However, using bootstrap server competent_kare:9092 or its ip-address 172.18.0.2:9092 and click on validate in the ui I still got
Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Commands which I used to verify the possibility of communication over the created network
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                       NAMES
17338825a793   ghcr.io/kafbat/kafka-ui   "/bin/sh -c 'java --…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   unruffled_hopper
0bc70820d669   apache/kafka:3.7.1        "/__cacert_entrypoin…"   11 minutes ago       Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp, :::9092->9092/tcp   competent_kare

$ docker exec -it competent_kare /bin/bash
0bc70820d669:/$ ping unruffled_hopper
PING unruffled_hopper (172.18.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=0 ttl=42 time=0.188 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=1 ttl=42 time=0.187 ms
^C
--- unruffled_hopper ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.181/0.185/0.188 ms
0bc70820d669:/$ ping 172.18.0.3
PING 172.18.0.3 (172.18.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=0 ttl=42 time=0.239 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=1 ttl=42 time=0.240 ms
^C
--- 172.18.0.3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.239/0.239/0.240 ms
0bc70820d669:/$ exit

$ docker exec -it unruffled_hopper /bin/sh
/ $ ping competent_kare
PING competent_kare (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=0 ttl=42 time=0.095 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=1 ttl=42 time=0.083 ms
^C
--- competent_kare ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.082/0.105/0.172 ms
/ $ ping 172.18.0.2
PING 172.18.0.2 (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=0 ttl=42 time=0.265 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=1 ttl=42 time=0.237 ms
^C
--- 172.18.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.237/0.251/0.265 ms
/ $ exit

Using the following port forwarding solved the issue finally.
$ docker exec -it --user=root unruffled_hopper /bin/sh
/ # apk add socat
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.4_p20231125-r0)
(2/4) Installing libncursesw (6.4_p20231125-r0)
(3/4) Installing readline (8.2.1-r2)
(4/4) Installing socat (1.8.0.0-r0)
Executing busybox-1.36.1-r15.trigger
OK: 191 MiB in 26 packages
/ # socat tcp-listen:9092,fork tcp:competent_kare:9092

I could in the GUI then connect via bootstrap server competent_kare:9092. The port forwarding seems to be necessary due to kafka returning a response that leads to a redirection to localhost:9092. So one solution seems to be to connect to the kafka host:port directly within the network. See as well Introduction to Apache Kafka.
I hope I've got that right.
Update
A solution which sets advertised listeners can be found here. It seems in that way there is no need to create a shared docker network and link the containers.
To run the docker compose file for the ui given in the post on linux I had to remove the volumes section at the end.
Exchanging the image with apache/kafka:3.7.1 in the kafka compose file does not work since a org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration zookeeper.connect which has no default value is returned on startup.

You should configure kafka advertised.listeners to fix the returned address after the bootstrap process. Using socat or communicating over the host network isn't necessary
